# How can I eliminate duplicates in a SQL Join?

Tags: php, sql

I am doing a web-based application in php for my university and I need to show how many students are taking some courses at the same time so they can avoid scheduling conflicts.

This my schema:

```
studentID   course   grade   program
324532      csc232   0       computer science
```

I am using php and this is the SQL query. I put grade 0 because he/she taking the course right now.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT s1.course AS c1 , s2.course AS c2 ,count(*) AS count 
FROM student s1 ,student s2  
WHERE  s1.studentID = s2.studentID 
AND s1.course!=s2.course AND s1.grade='0' AND s2.grade='0' GROUP BY s1.course,s2.course");
```

The answer I got is like this:

```
cscs321   csci322      6 // there is 6 students taking this two courses together
csci321   csci113      4 // there is 4 students taking these two subjects together
```

The problem is that I got some repeated results. For example csci321, csc322
is the same as csci322 and csci321.

How can I avoid this repetition?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this one:

```
SELECT
    s1.course AS c1,
    s2.course AS c2,
    count(s2.studentID) AS count
FROM student s1 
JOIN student s2 ON (
    s1.studentID = s2.studentID 
    AND s1.course<s2.course  -- <-- this line is important
    AND s1.grade='0' 
    AND s2.grade='0'
    )
GROUP BY
    s1.course,
    s2.course;
```

The idea is to "sort" the courses per line, so that

```
csci321, csc322
```

and

```
csc322, csci321
```

are considered the same, because `csc233 < csci321`

Comment: I'm left wondering why you are using an outer join: I can't see how having nulls in the resulset is helpful here.

Comment: thank u man , but i got other subjects with the subjects with grade 0, so the result has courses with grade more than 0 
for example i got csci103 1   (actually the grade for this is 70)
can u explain please

Comment: i got result like this 
csci103 1 

csci104 1

csci114 1

csci121 1

csci124 1

csci204 1

csci212 csci321 3

csci212 csci323 2

csci213 1

csci214 1

csci215 1

csci222 1

csci321 2

csci321 csci323 1

csci323 2

iact201 2

these courses with only one column i dont neeed

Comment: @onedaywhen, you're totally right. The outer join is unnecessary, it's just out of habit :-)

Comment: @user1092661: I changed the statement (replaced the `LEFT JOIN` with a `JOIN`). Now it should only return lines without the null

Answer (score -2):

You should use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` because you want the sum of students and not the count.

Comment: -1: unless you see something I don't, there isn't any field in that table that you could sum on; only grade and studentID are numeric, and summing them would be nonsensical.